# Button CSS weird results

Tags: css, button, css-position

I've been working on positioning  a button for a web app and ran into some difficulty.I've created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wold/3dk48/6/), which demonstrates the problem.

The code is taken out of context, so some of the rules and classes and such may not make sense, but the problem I'm having is the same. The button moves away on click and I can't seem to fix it when playing with the `position`. I want the button to stay in the same place when clicked, so that clicking on the button will actually take you to the link that it is referencing.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: seems like the position: inherit; and top:1px; on .back:active is causing the problem

Comment: remove this, .back:active

Comment: @Froient if I remove that, then the `.hover` animation doesn't play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the link move to `1px` from the top of the page in the rule `.back:active` (what happens when you click down on an item.)

http://jsfiddle.net/3dk48/8/

```
a.back:active {
    /* This breaks it.
    position: inherit;
    top:1px; */

    color: black;
}
```

In addition, if you want to still have `:active` effects, you need to have the correct specificity (currently `a.back:link` rule overrides your `color` for `:active`, but if you correctly update the specificity you can fix that. As well as link rule positioning in the LV(f)HA order (LoVe HAte mnemonic, plus focus lol) will ensure your pseudoclasses work properly.)

The LoVe-f-HAte mnemonic:

```
a:link { ... }
a:visited { ... }
a:focus { ... }
a:hover { ... }
a:active { ... }
```

... ensures that the correct states override the correct other states.

Comment: I guess that solves the problem, but is there not a way to have rules for `back.active`, yet also have the button not move when `active`?

Comment: Ok, seems to work, byte `a:hover` is still not working. Not in the jsfiddle you linked to at least.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the below code from `.back` style

```
position: absolute;   // not need
margin-left: 2%;      // not need
```

then the problem can solved.

**EDIT:**

also make change here..

```
.back:active {
    /* position: absolute;
       top: 1px; */
    color: black;
}
```

`fiddle`:  http://jsfiddle.net/3dk48/9/

Comment: Then I just get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Wold/3dk48/7/), which isn't really what I wanted.

Comment: If you remove both of those code segments, then it does;t shift, but `a.hover` still does not register.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
.back{
    top:32px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
body{
    position:relative;
}
```